# mail() function will not recognize message variables in php cronjob

Tags: php, email, cron

I have a text file called "basic.txt" with the following text

> This
>   is a 
>   test file.

My cronjob runs my php program every minute and sends me an email. I receive the email no problem, but it will not include the body message. Here is my php code:

```
<?php
    $string = "";
    $file = fopen("basic.txt", "r");
    $string .= file_get_contents("basic.txt");
    $fclose($file);
    echo $string; // this is to test that in fact $string contains the text and it does
    mail("example@hotmail.com", "TEST", $string, "From: example@hotmail.com");
?>
```

Why isn't $string sending the text from the text file to the body of the email even though I can use "echo $string" and it works fine?

Thanks

Comment: can you try `$string .= file_get_contents($file);` and/or put your `$fclose($file);` after mail is sent. Seems you may be closing the file too soon. check file permissions too.

Comment: $string .= file_get_contents($file); doesn't work, it says I need to have the filename there. $fclose($file); being after the mail function doesn't work either.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` does not require a `fopen()` and therefore the `fclose()` is also not needed

Comment: Are you saying the mail is not being SENT? Or that when you receive the mail it does not contain the contents of `basic.txt`

Comment: The mail is being sent, and I receive the subject head, just not the body where the input for that is $string

Comment: I deleted the file_get_contents() and fclose() and waiting to see what happens

Comment: @Michael it should work and it's most likely failing on you *silently*. I just tested this now.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that when I manually send the email using the command "php basic2.php", I receive it with the body saying "This is a test." The problem is that when I have my cronjob running the php script every minute, it doesn`t have "This is a test.", instead it is blank

Comment: Your system's error catching is probably set to continue to execute then and ignoring errors and keeps going. That's what I get from that. Using cron probably has its own mechanism to ignore the fail state and keeps executing. check your logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of these 2 lines:

```
 $file = fopen("basic.txt", "r");
 $fclose($file);
```

Since you're already using `file_get_contents()` which fetches the file's content.

Running your code from my server produced:

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /path/to/file.php on line 5

Your code is failing on you *silently*.

---

Therefore and in the OP's case and as per suggestions in comments, a full system path was required for the text file, and had to setup a new cron job.

Comment: I have done this and it still doesn't send to me. I left a comment above explaining what happened

Comment: @Michael Yes I saw that and responded with a comment also. Is there anything/code that you left out, or is that "it"? check your logs if you have access

Comment: @Michael another thing; are both files inside the same folder as the one you're executing from? If not, then you'll need to use a full system path for your text file, or use a full system path either way. I am pretty sure it has something to do with this. i.e.: `/var/user/public/folder/basic.txt`

Comment: No there is nothing I am leaving out. This was just a small test for a larger program i am writing and I am slowing adding functionality to find out where the problem is. It has to do with files because i created a local variable named $body = "Please work"; and changed the inputs to the mail function from "$string" to "$body" and the email I get has "Please work" in the body of the message. So it has to do with file input, just not sure what. As a refresher $string contained input from the text file

Comment: yes they are in the same folder as the one I'm executing from

Comment: @Michael either way, can you try a full system path to the text file and omitting the 2 lines as outlined in my answer. Plus, try setting up a new copy of the cron you're using now, there may be some caching happening and with what I already said about the system path.

Comment: @Michael Just to let you know Michael, that I setup a cron on my side with both files set inside the same folder (which is outside my public area) and is being sent successfully every minute. This as tested with what you posted minus the 2 lines of code I said to remove. Something else is causing this and you will need to further investigate this. There isn't much more I can do here, as much as I would like.

Comment: I set up a new crontab and added the entire path and it works! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Michael *Aaaahhhh, that's great* Michael, glad to hear it worked out :-) *Cheers!* and you're most welcome.

Comment: I have another question I'm posting about my bigger project which i'm running into a slightly different problem, it'd be great if you could take a look!

Comment: @Michael I'll keep an eye out for it Michael, I'll see what I can do. Others may also pick up on the question.